# Adding values to one columns based on conditions

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to update one column based on 2 columns

My example dataframe contains 3 columns

```
df <- data.frame(n1 = c(1,2,1,2,5,6),
                 n2 = c("a", "a", "a", NA, "b", "c"),
                 n3 = c("red", "red", NA, NA, NA, NA))

df

  n1   n2   n3
1  1    a  red
2  2    a  red
3  1    a <NA>
4  2 <NA> <NA>
5  5    b <NA>
6  6    c <NA>
```

I would like to add `red` name to row number `3` and `4` with the condition is that if values of `n1` (i.e. 1,2) match with `n2` (i.e. `a`), even though the fourth row (`n1` not match `n2`).

The main point is if `n2` == `a`, and values of `n1` associated with `a`, then values of `n3` that are the same row with values of `n1` should be added with `red`.

My desired output

```
  n1   n2   n3
1  1    a  red
2  2    a  red
3  1    a  red
4  2 <NA>  red
5  5    b <NA>
6  6    c <NA>
```

Any sugesstions for this case? I hope my explanation is clear enough. Since my data is very long, I am trying to find a good to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, create a logical vector to subset the rows of 'df' based on the `unique` values of 'n1' where 'n2' is "a", then do the assignment of 'n3' corresponding to that elements with the first non-NA element from 'n3'

```
i1 <- with(df, n1 %in% unique(n1[n2 %in% 'a']))
df$n3[i1] <- na.omit(df$n3[i1])[1]
```

-output

```
> df
  n1   n2   n3
1  1    a  red
2  2    a  red
3  1    a  red
4  2 <NA>  red
5  5    b <NA>
6  6    c <NA>
```

Comment: so far, that is the good one, but  I just found another condition that maybe used for this case, since the code applied to my data somehow just add `red` around 70% of cells

Comment: @Anh I am guessing that your original data may have some issues in the logical vector `i1`.  Here, it is created by checking which among the 'n1' values have 'n2' value as 'a'.  Is there something else going on i.e. having `"NA"` instead of `NA` in your data etc?  If those missing values are not `NA`, then `na.omit` won't remove those.  Not clear wihtout a reproducible small example that shows the issue

Comment: I gonna create a new post since I already found the problem

Answer (score 2):

Update:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(group = rep(row_number(), each=2, length.out = n())) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(n3 = ifelse(n1 %in% c(1,2) & any(n2 %in% "a", na.rm = TRUE), "red", n3)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group)
```

We could use an `ifelse` statement with conditions defined using `any`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(n3 = ifelse(n1==1 | n1==2 & any(n2[3:4] %in% "a"), "red", n3))
```

```
  n1   n2   n3
1  1    a  red
2  2    a  red
3  1    a  red
4  2 <NA>  red
5  5    b <NA>
6  6    c <NA>
```

Comment: are there another way without calling `1` or `2` since I have so many numbers

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: thank you so muchhhhh, I would like to make a new post since I just found a problem of my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(n1) %>%
  fill(n3) %>%
  group_by(n2) %>%
  fill(n3)
# # A tibble: 6 × 3
# # Groups:   n2 [4]
#      n1 n2    n3   
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 a     red  
# 2     2 a     red  
# 3     1 a     red  
# 4     2 NA    red  
# 5     5 b     NA   
# 6     6 c     NA
```

Comment: somehow, when I tried it, `red` name also added to somewhere that I dont want

Comment: but thank you so much#