# Adding values to columns based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, tidyverse, igraph

I have 1 `df` as below

```
df <- data.frame(n1 = c(1,2,1,2,5,6,8,9,8,8),
                 n2 = c(100,1000,500,1,NA,NA,2,8,10,15),
                 n3 = c("a", "a", "a", NA, "b", "c",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                 n4 = c("red", "red", NA, NA, NA, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
df
  n1   n2   n3   n4
1  1  100    a  red
2  2 1000    a  red
3  1  500    a <NA>
4  2    1 <NA> <NA>
5  5   NA    b <NA>
6  6   NA    c <NA>
7  8    2 <NA> <NA>
8  9    8 <NA> <NA>
9  8   10 <NA> <NA>
9  8   15 <NA> <NA>
```

First, please see my desired output

```
df
  n1   n2   n3   n4
1  1  100    a  red
2  2 1000    a  red
3  1  500    a  red
4  2    1 <NA>  red
5  5   NA    b <NA>
6  6   NA    c <NA>
7  8    2 <NA>  red
8  9    8 <NA> red
9  8   10 <NA> red
9  8   15 <NA> red
```

I made this post before ([Adding values to one columns based on conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69560941/adding-values-to-one-columns-based-on-conditions/69561104?noredirect=1#comment122952316_69561104)). However, I realized that I need to take one more column to solve my problem.

So, I would like to update/add the `red` in `n4` by asking the conditions comming from `n1`, `n2`, `n3`. If `n3 == "a"`, and values of n1 associated with a, then values of n4 that are the same row with values of n1 should be added with red (i.e. `row 3,4th`). At the same time, if values of `n1` also match with that of `n2` (i.e. `2`), then this row th of `n4` should also be added `red`. Further, `8` of column `n1` is connected with the entire things like that. Then, if we have futher values of `n2` or `n1` is equal to `8` then, the step would be replicated as before. I hope it is clear, if not I would like to explain more. (**It sounds like a Zig Zag thing**).

-Note: `tidyverse` and `baseR` also welcomed to help me here.

Any suggestions for me please?

Comment: Suppose your 9th row for 'n1' is 9, should that still be 'red' as 9 is connected to 8?

Comment: @akrun yes, that's what I want, since they are acting like a pipe

Comment: then, i am guessing it is related to igraph

Comment: I heard about it, but to be honestly, i have no knowledge about igraph

Comment: To be honestly, this is about a big phylogenetic tree, and the thing i am doing here is to find colour the branche representing the class of plants. The only way I can do is to find down the `common ancester` using `findMRCA` function, then set the colour. However, it seems to take much time to fill the colour completely since the tree is huge, so I would like to find a way like I posted here :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below if you are using `igraph`

```
res <- do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    decompose(
      graph_from_data_frame(replace(df, is.na(df), "NA"))
    ),
    function(x) {
      n4 <- E(x)$n4
      if (!all(n4 == "NA")) {
        E(x)$n4 <- unique(n4[n4 != "NA"])
      }
      get.data.frame(x)
    }
  )
)

dfout <- type.convert(
  res[match(do.call(paste, df[1:2]), do.call(paste, res[1:2])), ],
  as.is = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
> dfout
   from   to   n3   n4
1     1  100    a  red
2     2 1000    a  red
3     1  500    a  red
4     2    1 <NA>  red
9     5   NA    b <NA>
10    6   NA    c <NA>
5     8    2 <NA>  red
6     9    8 <NA>  red
7     8   10 <NA>  red
8     8   15 <NA>  red
```